# Plotting Pandas groupby two columns using subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have four columns, which are CAID, PID, BitRate and timeStamp.
Each CAID may have one or more PIDs.
I want to have each subplot for each CAID, and in each subplot PID stands for multiple lines, where x is time, y is bitrate.
At first, I used multiindex to fix the dataframe but failed.
Then I tried group by which gives me the same subplots.
I am just a starter. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.
The following are part of the dataFrame, my code and result.

DATA

```
CAID    PID   BitRate   timeStamp
1638    38      6016    57:07.3
1638    58      4512    57:07.3
3478    84      4512    57:07.3
1572    85      4512    57:07.3
1638    90      4512    57:07.3
1638    91      6016    57:07.3
1638    93      4512    57:07.3
3478    3376    4512    57:07.3
1572    3377    4512    57:07.3
1280    3378    15040   57:07.3
6168    3379    15040   57:07.3
6167    3380    15040   57:07.3
1572    3840    4512    57:07.3
3478    3841    4512    57:07.3
3478    3854    6016    57:07.3
```

CODE

```
grouped = ecmbw.groupby(['CAID','PID'])
nrows = int(math.ceil(len(grouped)/2.))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows,2)

for ax in axs.flatten():
    for i, j in grouped:
        j.plot(x='timeStamp',y='BitRate',ax=ax)
     ax = axs.next()
```

RESULT
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSSLD.png)